# parse json response into name value pair

Tags: apex, json

I have a json string , and i want it to be converted into name value pair json string.

**My actual string:**

```
 {"payload":[{"YearlylCostPercentage":"4.6",
 "TotalRepayment":"120000","PropertyMarketValue":"100000","productname":"Standard","PaymentFrequency":"Monthly","NumberOfTerms":"60","NotaryName":"Notary","NotaryEmail":"raj234eu222222222.sen@yahoo.com","NotaryContactNumber":"0234241729","NotaryAdressLine2":"1112 CM The Hag","NotaryAdressLine1":"Valkenboslaan 110","nominalInterestRate":"4.5","MonthlyPayment":"600","MonthlyInterestAmount":"300","loanUtilizationDate":"12-1-2019","loanPurpose":"Loan","loanMaturityDate":"12-2-2019","LoanDuration":"5","loanAmount":"100000","KadasterLocation":"Amsterdam","InterestFixationProvision":"1.0","HandlingCost":"900","FixedInterestyear":"2.0","firstPaymentDate":"12-2-2019","FirstMonthlyPayment":"700","effectiveInterestRate":"4.7","DepartmentName":"Dev","CustomerDetails":[{"CustomerSalutation":"Geen titulatuur gewenst","CustomerName":"Eqaavq","AddressLine2":"1221 NH MDFMGDAKSV","AddressLine1":"Wdr Veuniztapbmr 345"},{ "CustomerSalutation":"Mevrouw","CustomerName":"Eqaavq-col Fpcysfptp","AddressLine2":"1221 NH MDFMGDAKSV","AddressLine1":"Wdr Veuniztapbmr 345"}],"city":"Amsterdam","BorrowedRatio":"1.4","AdvisorName":"Raju Sen","AdvisorContact":"2123123312","AdviseCost":"1000"}]}';
```

**expected output :**

```
"payload":{
        {"name" : "YearlylCostPercentage",
        "value":"4.6"
         },
       {"name":"TotalRepayment",
       "value":"120000"
    }
```

Comment: That's basically JSON abuse. Why do you want/need it in this format?

Comment: Seems like this might be an X-Y problem. What will performing this transformation do for you? What ends up using this JSON? Is there a reason why you can't simply use `JSON.deserialize()` or `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`?

Comment: yeah, its an abuse, we are trying to connect with one of the services , they want the request body to have this format , so we can't use it as it is, we cant ask them to handle this from their end too.

Comment: Can we use json.createParser to form this output, iterating every attribute?

Comment: Okay, just realized your JSON expected output is invalid JSON. Are you *sure* that's correct?

Comment: sorry , i didnt notice my output , i just typed it here without even noticing. But your solution what i was looking for. Thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @sfdcfox i get this error on line 3 
System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to Map<String,ANY>,      its not a list yet but still i get this error

Comment: @RajuSen that indicates that the source JSON isn't as you described, either. Using JSON.deserializedUntyped is particularly finicky.

Comment: @sfdcfox i am having a hard time , i have no idea what i am missing here . I have updated the question with updated JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON.deserializeUntyped is your friend here:

```
Map<String, Object> jsonParseSource = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody);
List<Map<String, String>> payload = new List<Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, Object> payloadBody = (Map<String, Object>)jsonParseSource.get('payload');
for(String key: payloadBody.keyset()) {
  payload.add(new Map<String, String> { 'name' => key, 'value' => (String)payloadBody.get(key) });
}
String jsonResult = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> {
  'payload' => payload
});
```

This results in something like:

```
{ "payload": [
  { "name": "fieldname1", "value": "fieldvalue1" },
  { "name": "fieldname2", "value": "fieldvalue2" } ] }
```